# Piecewise function parameters for SED or Bandpass in GalSim

Tags: galsim

Is there a way to pass a piecewise (discontinuous) function for the "spec" parameter of SED or the "throughput" parameter of Bandpass? I tried passing a delta function and a triangular function using numpy, but galsim would not accept either as a valid python function.

I want to try drawing an object at a single wavelength, and thought I should modify the SED or the bandpass to have a value only at a single wavelength. If there are better ways to do this, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a better way to do this.

If you already have a ChromaticObject with some SED, you can get a GSObject corresponding to that ChromaticObject at a single wavelength using the ChromaticObject.evaluateAtWavelength() method.  Once you have that GSObject, you can draw it into an image.  For example:

```
sed = galsim.SED('wave**0.2')
sed2 = galsim.SED('wave**1.0')
obj = galsim.Gaussian(sigma=0.1)*sed + galsim.Gaussian(sigma=0.5)*sed2
foo = obj.evaluateAtWavelength(800.0) # argument is wavelength in nm
```

You can do this and find that obj is chromatic, while foo is not.  And you can do this easily for any number of wavelengths without having to redefine SEDs.

Comment: Agreed that this is probably what you want. But to your literal question, you can pass in any python function as the throughput or spec parameters. So these can be anything you want.  e.g. `bp = galsim.Bandpass(lambda wave:  0. if abs(wave-550) > 1. else 1., 549, 551)`

Comment: @Mike Jarvis It looks like this gives me an error as the code's figuring out the wavelength type. The code references self.wave_type.lower() -- and I thought the default was 'nm' -- but the AttributeError is that 'int' object has no attribute 'lower.'

Comment: @Gigi.  Sorry, I left out the wave_type.  Either add in 'nm' as the second argument (`galsim.Bandpass(..., 'nm', 549, 551)`) or use named kwargs for the limits (`galsim.Bandpass(..., blue_limit=549, red_limit=551)`).

Comment: @Mike Jarvis Thank you! Additionally, could you please help me understand why, when I try to drawImage using FFT with a piecewise SED (having the same function as your Bandpass example) and LSST filters, I get a ValueError "the truth value of an array with more than one element in ambiguous"? Where am I attempting to use the 'and' operator on two numpy arrays?